# python docx WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT member not detected

Tags: python, alignment, python-docx

So i was trying to align a table cell with code like this :

```
from docx import *
import re
from copy import deepcopy
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT, WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT as WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT as WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.style import WD_BUILTIN_STYLE
import sys

def writeNormalStyle(cell,fill):
cell.vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER
cell_bobot = cell.paragraphs[0]
cell_bobot.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
cell_bobot.text = fill

def writeBoldStyle(cell,fill):
cell.vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER
cell_paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
cell_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
cell_paragraph.add_run(fill).bold = True
```

but then error appeared Class 'WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT' has no 'CENTER' memberpylint(no-member)
i have no idea why this happen cause CENTER should exist in this class as the documentation said, and the error also apply to class WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

Thankyou, any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the code works as intended. This error appears to be coming from `pylint`, which perhaps is unable to detect the class members given to it by the metaclass that creates the enumeration. You may want to configure your linter to ignore this error.

Comment: Thankyou, sorry im new to this, i dont quite understand how to configure the linter like you said, can i ask for a direction on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Jolzal :) Don't neglect to accept an answer that resolves your question. You can find information on how to disable a pylint error on a specific line here: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html, something like adding `# pylint: disable=no-member` at the end of the offending line.